# Angular JS Shared functions between controllers

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I have this code:
http://jsbin.com/gazajunacu/1/edit?html,js,output

```
       angular.module('app', [])
        .service('greeting', function Greeting() {
          var greeting = this;
          greeting.message = '<strong>Default 2</strong>';
        })
        .controller('FirstCtrl', function ($sce, greeting) {
          var first = this;

          first.greeting = $sce.trustAsHtml(greeting);  
        })
        .controller('SecondCtrl', function (greeting) {
          var second = this;

          second.greeting = greeting;  
        })
```

And I cannot get it to spit html for first controller. I cannot get it working. Please check what's missing from the scripts.

Thanks.

Comment: Please include the code here in your question as well.  Also any elaboration on how it doesn't work would be good.

Comment: don't put blobs of code in comments, update the question itself so you can format the code

Comment: Ok - it's there in the Q.

Comment: Read the error message. Fix the error. you will find that the error has nothing to do with your shared function.

Comment: and one step better is use non minified version of angular for more verbose error output

Comment: your main problem is trying to use an object as a string, try using `greeting.message`

Comment: One other thing that won't directly solve your problem but that you should know : In angular, a controller should almost never output html. If you have to alter the html, it should normally be done in a directive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't include angular-sanitize.js in your libraries.

The correct way to achieve that is this : http://jsbin.com/rowukowuba/1/edit

Include angular-sanitize.js in the page and use ng-bind-html directive in the html page.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.5/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
```

```
<div>
  <span ng-bind-html="greeting"> </span> World
</div>
<div ng-controller="SecondCtrl as second">
  <span ng-bind-html="greeting.message"> </span> in Second
</div>
</body>
```

In the javascript, just place the html code in the scope and make sure that you include ngSanitize (i adapted your code) :

```
angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize'])
  .service('greeting', function Greeting() {
    var greeting = this;
    greeting.message = '<strong>Default 2</strong>';
  })
  .controller('FirstCtrl', function ($scope, greeting) {
  $scope.greeting = '<strong>Default 2</strong>';
  })
  .controller('SecondCtrl', function ($scope, greeting) {

    $scope.greeting = greeting;  
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

This should help

```
angular.module('app', [])
.service('greeting', function Greeting() {
    var greeting = this;
    greeting.message = '<strong>Default 2</strong>';
})
.controller('FirstCtrl', function (greeting) {
    var me = this;
    me.greeting = greeting;  
})
.controller('SecondCtrl', function ($scope,greeting) {

    var me = this;
    me.greeting = greeting;  
})
```

;

The following row created your error

```
first.greeting = $sce.trustAsHtml(greeting);
```

Comment: I want to display html contents so the code is correct trustAsHtml.

Comment: in your view you refer to greeting like it was on the scope. when you write {{ greeting.message }} is the same as in the controller talk to a property called greeting so basically $scope.greeting.message